# why did the method in the component class did not get called when an item is chosen from the select box?

Tags: angular

Hi I have an angular 5 application. I have a select box in my component template html file and a method in the component class that will be invoked when i we select an item from the drop down box. However It is not working. please find the code below

```
  <select formControlName="inventory" [compareWith]="compareInventory" change="inventoryChanged($event.target.value);">
          <option value="" disabled>{{ 'PLACEHOLDERS.SELECT_INVENTORY' | translate }}</option>
          <option *ngFor="let inventory of inventories" [ngValue]="inventory">{{ inventory.label }}</option>
        </select>
```

in the component ts file

```
  inventoryChanged(inventorySelected){
    console.log("inventory changed");
  }
```

i am expecting this inventoryChanged to call and log it into the console. however i cannot see anything got logged int he developer tool.
appreciate any help

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `(change)="inventoryChanged($event.target.value);"`? We add parenthesis for lsitening to events in angular

Comment: yes you are right . my mistake. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you for got the round brace. so your binding not working as expected

```
  <select formControlName="inventory" [compareWith]="compareInventory" (change)="inventoryChanged($event.target.value);">
          <option value="" disabled>{{ 'PLACEHOLDERS.SELECT_INVENTORY' | translate }}</option>
          <option *ngFor="let inventory of inventories" [ngValue]="inventory">{{ inventory.label }}</option>
        </select>
```